GeoList Labeled places
I want to list a number of cities on a map with numbers, but I am getting strange results.
GeoListPlot[{Labeled[Entity["City", {"Helsinki", "Uusimaa", "Finland"}], 
   Style["1", {Black, 15}]], 
  Labeled[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Style["2", {Red, 15}]], 
  Labeled[Entity["City", {"Helsinki", "Uusimaa", "Finland"}], 
   Style["3", {Black, 15}]], , 
  Labeled[Entity["City", {"Ottawa", "Ontario", "Canada"}], 
   Style["4", {Red, 15}]]}, GeoLabels -> Automatic, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[18, Red], Joined -> True]



The "1" is a "move over-popup". The Ottowa "4" is not there. What is wrong? The errors are robust to trying other overall options.

You can force the labels to be shown by giving the position as the third argument of Labeled. Otherwise, the heuristics tries to determine the optimal positions, and it resolves collisions by putting them in callouts.
Oh, and note that label 4 was not appearing, because you had a double comma in the list!
GeoListPlot[{
  Labeled[Entity["City", {"Helsinki", "Uusimaa", "Finland"}], 
   Style["1", {Black, 15}], Above],
  Labeled[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Style["2", {Red, 15}]],
  Labeled[Entity["City", {"Helsinki", "Uusimaa", "Finland"}], 
   Style["3", {Black, 15}], Below],
  Labeled[Entity["City", {"Ottawa", "Ontario", "Canada"}], 
   Style["4", {Red, 15}]]}, Joined -> True]



I had a work around by using GeoPosition with values near Helsinki.
